# STL Algorithms to generate and copy a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

Can you please tell me how to do the following using STL algorithms?

```
// Create a vector of 50 elements, and assign elem value same as index value
std::vector<int> a(50);
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}

// Create another vector by copying a section of vector a
std::vector<int> b;
size_t ind = 20;
b.resize(a.size() - ind);
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
{
    b[i] = a[i+ind];
}
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a new vector b, from vector a, by skipping the first 'ind' elements of a.

Comment: Best indicate which blocks may be combined for better effect. (and what's wanted resp. an artifact of the question)

Comment: Hint: `std::vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators.

Comment: @Deduplicator, essentially 2 blocks, as per my edit

Comment: @juanchopanza, Got it! That does the second block, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably do it something like this:

```
std::vector<int> a(50);

// fill a with 0..N
std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);

size_t ind = 20;

// initialize `b` from elements of `a`:    
std::vector<int> b{a.begin()+ind, a.end()};
```

You could use `std::copy` for the second part, but for the case at hand I'd prefer to initialize `b` from the iterators as I've done above.

Answer (score 1):

With boost you could do the first part with initialization as well (see Jerry's answer).

```
auto r = boost::irange(0,50);
auto a = std::vector<int>(std::begin(r), std::end(r));
```

Eric Neibler's range library I think includes this type of thing and I fully expect it'll make it into C++17.  Until then you have to use his or boost's as a third-party lib.

Comment: Holy moly super insane awesome

Comment: Can r in this case be something other than a std::vector?

Comment: @user3670482: Yes, in this case `r` is *not* a `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

constructor as follows.

```
auto start = std::next(a.begin(), 20);
std::vector<int> b(start, a.end());
```